# How to get to the dimension added in the Emerald mod

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

In the Minecraft Modinstaller,a part of description of the Emerald mod says that a new dimension is added. How can I get to it?

Comment: Does Arqade still support Modded questions? I thought it was only for Vallina Minecraft?

Comment: @ExplosionsPlus I think Arqade allows questions about mods as long as they're not asking for tech support. For example, "Minecraft forge keeps crashing" is usually put on hold and closed. Questions like this are fine.

Comment: Whatever you say :D Juust checking :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a portal five blocks tall and four blocks wide, and use Emerald Obsidian instead of plain old Obsidian.

[image: Emerald Obsidian Crafting Recipe]

Strike the inside of the portal with Flint and Emerald, not flint and steel.

[image: Flint and Emerald Crafting Recipe]

Have fun in the Emerald biome!

Answer (score 1):

You have to build a portal just like for the Nether, except you have to use [Emerald Obsidian](http://emerald-mod.wikia.com/wiki/Emerald_Obsidian).

[image: Emerald Obsidian schematics]